# Solution to 2D stationary Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have a Fokker-Planck equation which looks like

$$ 0 = \partial_x (F_1 P - D_x\partial_xP ) + \partial_y (F_2 P - D_y\partial_yP )$$

where $F_1  = F_1(x,y) = -k_x(x - 1/(1+e^{-y}))$ and $F_2 = -k_y(x-c)$ where $k_x,k_y>0$ and $c>0$ are constants. Also, constants $D_x,D_y > 0$. Since $P$ is a probability distribution it must be normalizable in its domain which is $x\in [0,1]$ and $y\in[0,L]$ for a positive, finite $L$.

Also, I would like to point out that $P$ does not necessarily vanish at the domain boundaries.

Is there a way to solve this PDE for a general solution?

I tried a few methods but nothing worked so far.

It would really help if someone could suggest a way to approach this problem.

Thanks a lot!